# Get current URL, edit it and output into textarea

Tags: jquery, url, input

I wanted to create a small script, that will get the user's current URL, and modify it so it will link to an element on the page using ID anchor. I have the basics covered here, but i cannot wrap my mind around the logic, how to make it possible. There are some different possible URL states:

1) **example.ex/test/**

2) **example.ex/test/page.html**

3) **example.ex/test/#** or **example.ex/test/#old-id**

4) **example.ex/test/page.html#** or **example.ex/test/page.html#old-id**

I need to remove everything what is not needed, but in different situations i need to remove different symbols. In cases 1 and 2 i can just add #id to the end, and the link will be correct. In cases 3 and 4 i need to remove the # and everything after it, and then add the new #id. Any help with the logic? Thanks in advance.

```
$(".fast-link").on('click', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var url = $(location).attr('href'); // get current browser link
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id"); // get parent's ID

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) { 
        // need to remove everything after # from url variable and insert (# + id) variable
    } else {
        $('#fastLinkInput').val( url + "#" + id );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove the hash from the URL if it has one.

```
if (url.indexOf("#") > -1) {
    url = url.slice(0, url.indexOf("#"));
}
$("#fastLinkInput").val(url + "#" + id);
```